# How to create a windows service for an executable application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, windows-services

So I made a .exe application which runs perfectly fine. But, now I have a requirement to run a background service for a particular reason which is related to this application. I figured out how to make a windows service and it's working, But I had to install the service manually by going to the CMD and using the service manager.

How do I install the service along with the installation of the executable that I made?
Because otherwise, everyone who uses this .exe will need to install the service manually by going to the CMD.

Comment: Give them a batch file that carries out the `sc /install` or whatever you did to install the service

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

```
sc.exe create <new_service_name> binPath= "<path_to_the_service_executable>"
```